# Keras KerasClassifier gridsearch TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, grid-search

The following code is throwing an error:
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

I can see that it likely has to do with passing the previous method in as a function in def fit(self, c_m). But I think this is correct via the documentations: https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/

I may be making a rookie mistake if anyone sees the error in my code I would appreciate help.

```
np.random.seed(7)
y_dic = []

class NN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.X = None
        self.y = None
        self.model = None

    def clean_data(self):
        seed = 7
        np.random.seed(seed)
        dataset = pd.read_csv('/Users/isaac/pca_rfe_tsne_comparisons/Vital_intrusions.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=0)
        dataset = dataset.iloc[:,1:6]
        self.X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:5]
        Y = dataset.iloc[:, 0]

        for y in Y:
            if y >= 8:
                y_dic.append(1)
            else:
                y_dic.append(0)
        self.y = y_dic

        self.X = np.asmatrix(stats.zscore(self.X, axis=0, ddof=1))
        self.y = to_categorical(self.y)


    def create_model(self):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        pass

    def fit(self, c_m):
        model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=c_m, verbose=0)
        batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
        epochs = [10, 50, 100]
        param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
        grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
        pdb.set_trace()
        grid_result = grid.fit(self.X, self.y)
        return (grid_result)

    def results(self, grid_results):
        print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
        means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
        stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
        params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
        for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
            print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))


def main():
    nn = NN()
    nn.clean_data()
    nn.create_model()
    grid_results = nn.fit(nn.create_model)
    nn.results(grid_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ok, a follow up to this. Thanks for your comments @MarcinMożejko. You were right about this. There were more errors I should mention. In def fit(), I wrote model = KerasClassifier, not self.model=Keras Classifier. I wanted to mention that incase anyone is looking at the code. I'm now getting a new error on the same line:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loss'.

I can track this back to scikit_learn.py:

```
loss_name = self.model.loss
        if hasattr(loss_name, '__name__'):
            loss_name = loss_name.__name__
        if loss_name == 'categorical_crossentropy' and len(y.shape) != 2:
            y = to_categorical(y)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this as I set the loss term in self.model.compile. I tried changing it to binary_crossentropy but that had no effect. any further thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in this line of code:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

Unfortunately - for now, `keras` is not supporting applying `pickle` to your model which is needed for `sklearn` to apply multiprocessing ([here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/789) you may read the discussion on this). In order to make this code work you should set:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments @MarcinMożejko. You were right about this. There were more errors I should mention. In def fit(), I wrote model = KerasClassifier, not self.model=Keras Classifier. I wanted to mention that incase anyone is looking at the code. I'm now getting a new error on the same line: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loss'.

Comment: There are about a dozen different solutions for the given error, this is the only one that worked for me. Thanks!